# Blank video in Firefox (Mac) using mediaelement.js

Tags: html5-video, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

Using mediaelement.js with great success except for Firefox on Mac OS X where the video seems to load fine and display the correct duration and the play head scrubs - the only problem is that the video is blank unlike in Firefox on Windows and all other browsers.

We are using the single h.264 option.

Sporadically we also see this error in Firefox on OS X randomly on page load - *Error: this.pluginAPI.playMedia is not a function*

Anybody have any ideas?